# JavaFX expand ListView/TableView height to full size

Tags: listview, javafx, layout, tableview, fxml

I have a simple FXML layout:

```
<ScrollPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <VBox>
        <Label text="Hello"/>
        <Label text="Expand listview"/>
        <ListView fx:id="listViewTest"/>
    </VBox>
</ScrollPane>
```

When there are a lot of items in ListView it gets its own scrollbar.

Is there a way to make ListView grow to full size and expand its parent -
 VBox, in the end having only one scrollbar of the ScrollPane?

Comment: "When there are a lot of items in ListView it gets its own scrollbar." This can happen if there are a large enough number of items, no matter what you do with the layout. (It's always possible for there to be more items than you have room to display.) Are you sure you want the scroll pane at all? It's probably better *only* to use the scrolling provided by the `ListView`.

Comment: The better question is should you be putting your `ListView` in a `ScrollPane` in this case?

Comment: @James_D the reason I want it like that is because other elements(labels in this case) can take up a lot of space that don't fit in the screen and I need ScrollPane for it, but I also need to display ListView inside and two vertical bars is just a bit annoying.

Comment: You can configure the `ListView` to consume as much space in the `VBox` as possible, but you cannot remove the possibility of two scroll bars. Try `VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"` and `maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"` as attributes for the `ListView`.

Comment: @James_D doesn't seem to work. Before I was expanding it by setting prefHeight to high value, looping through all cells, and summing up their heights, then setting listView prefHeight to the sum of cell heights, but it doesn't really feel right.

Comment: Well, it's simply not right: this is not the way a `ListView` (or `TableView`) is designed to work. The whole point of these controls is that they do not create cells for all the data, enabling you to display very large data sets without consuming prohibitively large amounts of memory. Since there aren't cells for all the data, it's not really possible to compute a preferred size to display everything. You probably need to reconsider the approach here: perhaps a `ListView` is not what you want at all.